# Parse json object with arrays

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json in this form:

```
 var test = { "name1" : [ "aaa", "bbb"], "name2" : [ "ccc", "ddd" ] };
```

I've tried to iterate this like

```
for (var names in test )
{
    for ( var element in names )
    {
        // problem we got the chars in the "names1", etc
    }
}
```

What exactly I missed?

Comment: That's not JSON, that's just a Javascript object.

Comment: `console.log(names);` - try it and ensure that every variable in your code contains the expected data

Comment: A `for in` loop loops over keys, not values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate `test` object you need something like this:

```
for(var key in test) //iterate object keys
{
    var elements = test[key];
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) //iterate array indexes
    {
        var element = elements[i];
    }
}
```